# Does it make sense for a package to depend on, e.g. import, its nested packages?

Tags: design, uml, packages

I think depending on nested packages is wrong, because the nested packages are always going to depend on the parent —aren't they?– and this can lead to cyclic dependency issues.

When I look at how UML alternatively represents package dependency, it shows the anchor icon in an unidirectional way, e.g. the nested packages depending on its parent, and never the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, depending on nested packages is wrong.

Conceptually packages should represent different levels of abstraction, starting from the root package (the most abstract) down to the leaf packages (most concrete). In this concept depending on nested packages means abstract things depend on more concrete things, which is obviously wrong even if it doesn't introduce cyclic dependencies.

Some projects however use packages as a way of just "grouping" classes according to some internal logic, not based on the abstractions of the problem domain. It is easy to see this makes the project less maintainable, since readers need to descent into packages to understand what's going on instead stopping at the right abstraction level.

I have more details to this argument in [this article](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/happy-packaging/).